# ViewModel SavedStateHandler.get for LiveData can't set default value as per the document?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-savedstate

In referring to https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle#getLiveData(java.lang.String,%20T)

The sample codes in Java as below.

```
 String defaultValue = ...; // nullable
 LiveData<String> liveData;
 if (defaultValue != null) {
     liveData = savedStateHandle.get(KEY, defaultValue);
 } else {
     liveData = savedStateHandle.get(KEY);
 }
```

However, I notice that when tried to compile the code, the statement below is not compilable.

```
savedStateHandle.get(KEY, defaultValue);
```

It error out stating

```
get(String) in SavedStateHandle cannot be applied to (String, java.lang.String).
```

I trace into the code, and seems like `savedStatehandle` doesn't have a `get` that takes in a default value. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Google Document has typo. It supposed to be

```
 String defaultValue = ...; // nullable
 LiveData<String> liveData;
 if (defaultValue != null) {
     liveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(KEY, defaultValue);
 } else {
     liveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(KEY);
 }
```

i.e. `getLiveData` instead of just `get`.