# How to save LiveData into saveStateHandle?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-savedstate

As shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166665/3286489, we could save LiveData in savedStateHandle.

I could do that easily
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166665/3286489

```
private val textLiveData: MutableLiveData<String>

init {
    textLiveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(KEY)
}
```

However, when trying to save it as below,

```
savedStateHandle.set(KEY, textLiveData)
```

I got the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't put value with type class androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle$SavingStateLiveData into saved state
```

Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: Try that way `savedStateHandle.set(KEY, textLiveData.value)`

Comment: @Parth this is bad advice (well, not the best advice). You can use `val textLiveData: MutableLiveData<String> = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(KEY)` which constructs a `MutableLiveData` that is automatically persisted to `savedInstanceState`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the better answer is, we don't even need to

```
savedStateHandle.set(KEY, textLiveData.value)
```

While that is permissible, when we one do set

```
textLiveData.value = "Some data"
```

This already saved to the state. As `textLiveData` is retrieved from `savedStateHandle` as below.

```
textLiveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(KEY)
```

Hence the `textLiveData` is already stored within the `savedStateHandle`, and changes to `textLiveData.value` is inadvertently get saved in `savedStateHandle`.

Comment: Refer to https://medium.com/@elye.project/unintuitive-livedata-savedstatehandle-3d01fbdbfc01 for more details of the finding.

Comment: so what is the solution?how to remove the exception?

Answer (score 11):

That is because your you class is not acceptable.
You can put `Parcelable` or `Serializable` types.

Here is the list of `ACCEPTABLE_CLASSES`

```
private static final Class[] ACCEPTABLE_CLASSES = new Class[]{
        //baseBundle
        boolean.class,
        boolean[].class,
        double.class,
        double[].class,
        int.class,
        int[].class,
        long.class,
        long[].class,
        String.class,
        String[].class,
        //bundle
        Binder.class,
        Bundle.class,
        byte.class,
        byte[].class,
        char.class,
        char[].class,
        CharSequence.class,
        CharSequence[].class,
        // type erasure ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, we won't eagerly check elements contents
        ArrayList.class,
        float.class,
        float[].class,
        Parcelable.class,
        Parcelable[].class,
        Serializable.class,
        short.class,
        short[].class,
        SparseArray.class,
        (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? Size.class : int.class),
        (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? SizeF.class : int.class),
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `val textLiveData: MutableLiveData<String> = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(KEY)` which constructs a `MutableLiveData` that is automatically persisted to `savedInstanceState`.

> savedStateHandle.set(KEY, textLiveData)

You don't need to do this, because `getLiveData` is a `SavingStateLiveData` which automatically handles this.

Answer (score -2):

After looking into the code, realize I just need to save the value, as what @Parth mentioned in the comment above.

```
savedStateHandle.set(KEY, textLiveData.value)
```

**Explanation**

If we look into the `set` of `SavedStateHandle.java`

```
@MainThread
public <T> void set(@NonNull String key, @Nullable T value) {
    validateValue(value);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    MutableLiveData<T> mutableLiveData = (MutableLiveData<T>) mLiveDatas.get(key);
    if (mutableLiveData != null) {
        // it will set value;
        mutableLiveData.setValue(value);
    } else {
        mRegular.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

This shows that it will put the data into the `mutableLiveData` that we store in `mLiveDatas` if there is one.

To ensure that our liveData is in `mLiveDatas`, we just need to use `textLiveData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(KEY)` at the start. Checkout the `getLiveData` of 
`SavedStateHandle.java`

```
@NonNull
private <T> MutableLiveData<T> getLiveDataInternal(
        @NonNull String key,
        boolean hasInitialValue,
        @Nullable T initialValue) {
    MutableLiveData<T> liveData = (MutableLiveData<T>) mLiveDatas.get(key);
    if (liveData != null) {
        return liveData;
    }
    SavingStateLiveData<T> mutableLd;
    // double hashing but null is valid value
    if (mRegular.containsKey(key)) {
        mutableLd = new SavingStateLiveData<>(this, key, (T) mRegular.get(key));
    } else if (hasInitialValue) {
        mutableLd = new SavingStateLiveData<>(this, key, initialValue);
    } else {
        mutableLd = new SavingStateLiveData<>(this, key);
    }
    mLiveDatas.put(key, mutableLd);
    return mutableLd;
}
```

It will create one and put into `mLiveDatas` when we request for one, if there isn't one already.